# Disable 'submit' button unless box is checked

Tags: javascript, forms, preventdefault

Following on from a previous question I asked
[Submit button not working with JS validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72773527/18227124)

I have been really struggling with getting the checkbox being checked to be part of the form validation.

my html is

```
    <h1>Applicant Form</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="create-lead.php" id="newLead" class="form" method="POST">
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" id="firstName">
          <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field ">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" id="lastName">
          <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
          <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone">
          <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field dropdown">
          <label for="buyerType" class="buyerType">Application Type</label>
          <select class="secondary" name="buyerType" id="buyerType">
            <option value="Purchase">Purchase</option>
            <option value="FirstTimeBuyer">First Time Buyer</option>
            <option value="Remortgage">Remortgage</option>
            <option value="RaiseFunds">Raise Funds</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label class="check-container" for="accept">
              <input class="check" type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" value="yes">
              I agree to the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
            </label>
          <small></small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field buttons">
          <input class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">
          <input class="clear" type="reset" name="reset" id="reset">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

and the app.js is

```
const firstNameEl = document.querySelector('#firstName');
const lastNameEl = document.querySelector('#lastName');
const emailEl = document.querySelector('#email');
const telephoneEl = document.querySelector('#telephone');
const checkedEl = document.getElementById('#accept');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('#submitButton');

const form = document.querySelector('#newLead');

const checkFirstName = () => {
    let valid = false;

    const firstName = firstNameEl.value.trim();

    if (!isRequired(firstName)) {
        showError(firstNameEl, 'First name cannot be left blank');
    } else if (!isFirstNameValid(firstName)) {
        showError(firstNameEl, 'First name must only contain letters');
    } else {
        showSuccess(firstNameEl);
        valid = true;
    };
    return valid;
};

const checkLastName = () => {
    let valid = false;

    const lastName = lastNameEl.value.trim();

    if (!isRequired(lastName)) {
        showError(lastNameEl, 'Last name cannot be left blank');
    } else if (!isLastNameValid(lastName)) {

        showError(lastNameEl, 'Last name must only contain letters');

    } else {
        showSuccess(lastNameEl);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};

const checkEmail = () => {
    let valid = false;
    const email = emailEl.value.trim();
    if (!isRequired(email)) {
        showError(emailEl, 'Email field cannot be left blank');
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        showError(emailEl, 'Email is not valid')
    } else {
        showSuccess(emailEl);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};
const checkTelephone = () => {
    let valid = false;
    const telephone = telephoneEl.value.trim();
    if (!isRequired(telephone)) {
        showError(telephoneEl, 'Telephone field cannot be left blank');
    } else if (!isTelephoneValid(telephone)) {
        showError(telephoneEl, 'Number is not valid')
    } else {
        showSuccess(telephoneEl);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};

// const checkedElValid = () => {
//     if (!document.querySelector('#submitButton').checked) {
//         showError(, 'You must accept the terms to continue')
//     } else {
//         showSuccess(accept);
//         valid = true;
//     }
//     return valid;
// };

const isFirstNameValid = (firstName) => {
    const re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    return re.test(firstName);
};

const isLastNameValid = (lastName) => {
    const re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    return re.test(lastName);
};


const isEmailValid = (email) => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
};

const isTelephoneValid = (telephone) => {
    const re = /^[0-9]+$/;
    return re.test(telephone);
};

const isRequired = value => value === '' ? false : true;


const showError = (input, message) => {
    const formField = input.parentElement;
    formField.classList.remove('success');
    formField.classList.add('error');

    const error = formField.querySelector('small');
    error.textContent = message;
};

const showSuccess = (input) => {
    const formField = input.parentElement;

    formField.classList.remove('error');
    formField.classList.add('success');

    const error = formField.querySelector('small');
    error.textContent = '';
}


form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    //validate fields
    let isFirstNameValid = checkFirstName(),
        isLastNameValid = checkLastName(),
        isEmailValid = checkEmail(),
        isTelephoneValid = checkTelephone();
        IsCheckedElValid = checkedElValid();


    let
        isFormValid = 
        isFirstNameValid &&
        isLastNameValid &&
        isEmailValid &&
        isTelephoneValid &&
        IsCheckedElValid;


    if (!isFormValid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitButton.disabled;
    } else {
        submitButton.disabled == false;

    };

});
// real time validation
const debounce = (fn, delay = 500) => {

    let timeoutId;

    return (...args) => {
        if (timeoutId) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            fn.apply(null, args)
        }, delay);
    };
};
//event delegation
form.addEventListener('input', debounce(function(e) {
    switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'firstName':
            checkFirstName();
            break;
        case 'lastName':
            checkLastName();
            break;
        case 'email':
            checkEmail();
            break;
        case 'telephone':
            checkTelephone();
            break;
    }
}));
```

I have included the commented out section because that is the function I am working on to try and include the checkbox as part of the validation.

Everything else works perfectly, but I need to ensure the user accepts the terms and conditions before the form can be sent.

It seems that `e.preventDefault()` and `submitButton.disabled` aren't working as expected, unless I am missing something..

I am relatively new, and don't have the experience to get this working properly!

edit

On the advice of https://stackoverflow.com/a/72778291/18227124

I am rewriting the final validation to

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    //validate fields
    let isFirstNameValid = checkFirstName(),
        isLastNameValid = checkLastName(),
        isEmailValid = checkEmail(),
        isTelephoneValid = checkTelephone();
    let
        isFormValid = 
        isFirstNameValid &&
        isLastNameValid &&
        isEmailValid &&
        isTelephoneValid;

    if (isFormValid) {
        let submitBtn = document.querySelector("button");
        let checkBox = document.getElementById("accept");

        checkBox.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (checkBox.checked) {
                submitBtn.disabled == false;
            } else {
                submitBtn.disabled == true;
            }
        });
    };
    
});
```

but again, I don't think I have implemented it correctly

Comment: Just curious why you aren't using the [built-in HTML5 validation features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: @ScottMarcus the brief for the project included highly specific error messages and real-time validation. This seemed to be the best way I could find to satisfy the brief. Ive only fallen at a few hurdles so far, and this is the final one.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ive edited my question, with how I think I should implement the code snippet you provided.

Comment: No, you should set up the checkbox event handler outside of the `form`s event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too long and involved to examine, but the basic idea is not to let the user click the submit button until they have passed all validations, rather than allow them to click submit and then see if everything is valid.

So we set up a `click` event handler on the checkbox that simply enables or disables the submit button based on whether the checkbox is checked. When done this way, there is no need for `preventDefault()`.

Here's a scaled down example that you can incorporate into your code:

```js
let submitBtn = document.querySelector("button");
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(this.checked){
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    submitBtn.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"> I agree to the terms.
<button disabled>Submit</button>
```